# CSS styles and jQuery Events do not apply on ajax-loaded HTML

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, laravel-5.5, icheck

I am working on Laravel Framework, for showing list of products, with each product and respective product details embedded in a div, so different divs appear correctly aligned on the page. Every product div is given an icheck checkbox to compare two products.

There are also filters on the same page, like brands, price etc., each associated with checkbox initialized with icheck. When I click on filter checkbox, the products from backend appear on front end using **jQuery Ajax.**

There is different blade created for creating view of products, same as that appears on initial page load. That view is rendered by Laravel's `view()->render()` method and shown on front end using `element.html()` method.

The problem is that already loaded styles and events for icheck and other buttons do not work for ajax-loaded html contents.

To make it success, I had to write something like

```
$(document).on("ifChanged", '.compare_products input[type="checkbox"].minimal-red', function(){
            var test = $(this).val();

            var yourArray = [];
            count = 0;
            $('.compare_products input[type="checkbox"].minimal-red:checked').each(function(){
                yourArray.push({'p_id' : $(this).data('val'), 'prod_name' : $(this).data('prod_name')});

            });
            compare(yourArray, this);
        })
```

So then I had no problem with events. But CSS styles (margin, padding etc.) for different buttons, e.g. Buy Now button were not applied.

So can anyone please suggest me solution over the problem?

Comment: Can you include the HTML and CSS?

Comment: I am sorry for the same. I am not allowed to expose more code. Apologies. But still I will still try to add more code shortly.